# Multiple IF statements: IF, AND, ISDATE, THEN formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to get a nested formula to work, but I keep getting an error. I tried using the generic formula `=IF(AND(A1="this",B1="that"),"x","")` but couldn't figure out how to make sure Q6=date. I had another reviewer write a code for me to conditionally format a cell with similar criteria and it worked so I figured I could use it for this situation. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can someone kindly help me understand what I did wrong?

If both these conditions are met:

- P6 = "closed"

AND

- Q6 = date

Then:

- Q6-P6 (subtract)
- otherwise, leave blank

**EDIT: added this second condition: any errors or negative values that result become "NA". I think it will be some sort of nested statement?**

**IF: negative number or error (#VALUE!)**

**THEN: "NA"**

---

Formulas I tried:

`=IF( AND(ISDATE(Q6), COUNTIFS(P6, "closed",  Q6, ">"&DATE(0,1,1)), "Q6-B6", ""))`

AND

`=IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6">"&DATE( 0,1,1), Q6-B6, ""))`

AND

`=IF(AND(P6= “closed”, ISDATE(Q6 ">"&DATE(0,1,1))), Q6-B6, "")`

---

### Solution #1

I figured it out! Was a simple fix; just set the second condition as any date less than today.

`=IF(AND(P6="closed",  Q6<"Today()"), Q6-B6, "")`

**BUT now if I get a negative number (because column B doesn't have a start date), how can I make this formula return "NA?"**

I tried this formula (got an error):

`=IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"Today()", Q6-B6, ""), IF(R6<0, "NA", IF(R6="VALUE!", "NA", "NA")))`

Am I on the right track? Does this fail because if it errors/is negative is circular (it's the result of the first part of the formula running)? I got the negative value to disappear using conditional formatting and making the text font white (thank you, @user0!)

Should the error piece be written as an array/error trap? the IFERROR code completely confuses me. I tried these but still got `Formula parse error`:

`=iferror(ArrayFormula(IF(AND(P6="closed")*(Q6<"Today()"),Q6-B6), "NA”))`

`=iferror(ArrayFormula(IF(AND(P6="closed")*( Q6<"Today()"),Q6-B6, “”),1)`

`=iferror(ArrayFormula(IF(AND(P6="closed")*( Q6<"Today()"),Q6-B6, “”),1,"NA")`

### Solution #2

Wow. I feel pretty accomplished. Lots of trial and error, but this formula seems to work for all cases. Gives me the count Q6-B6, NA if there's an error, and blank if conditions aren't met (the negative values I used conditional formatting to hide).

**`=IFERROR(IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"Today()"), Q6-B6, ""), "NA")`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1

I think I figured it out! I just set the second condition to be a date less than today (since the dates in column Q will be the closure date, they are dates in the past). I modified the generic IF-AND formula:

`=IF(AND(P6="closed",  Q6<"Today()"), Q6-B6, "")`

### Solution #2

For the negative values, I used conditional formatting and made the text white (credit goes to @user0, who helped me with another issue and used this ingenious trick)

For the errors, I used an error trap formula (also thanks to @user0). Took a little tweaking and a lot of trial and error, but I finally got it to work!! :)

**`=IFERROR(IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"Today()"), Q6-B6, ""), "NA")`**

Answer (score 1):

**`=IFERROR(IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"Today()"), Q6-B6, ""), "NA")`**

can be slightly improved to:

```
=IFERROR(
         IF(
            AND(P6 = "closed"; 
                Q6 < "NOW()"); 
                               IF((Q6-B6) < 0; 
                                               ""; 
                                               Q6-B6); 
                               ""); 
         "NA")
```

- where `NOW()` is for more accuracy (if needed), because it can include the already passed time of today's day.
- and 2nd `IF()` is able to detect and capture negative values, so there is no need for conditional formatting

---

**final solution for OP:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(P6="never opened", "",
         IF(B6="", "", 
         IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"NOW()"), Q6-B6, TODAY()-B6))),)
```

Comment: condition1: if P6=never opened, then blank OR condition2: if P6=closed AND Q6<today, then Q6-B6, otherwise TODAY() -B6. the `IFERROR` helped hide any errors

Comment: i slightly modified my original conditions (see comment above). my current formula: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(P6="never opened", "", IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"Today()"), Q6-B6, TODAY()-B6))))` it works great (no negative values), but if B6 is empty, then R6 ends up being a string of numbers that changes every day. today it's `43329`, yesterday =`43328`, 2 days ago = `43327`, etc. how do i get this go way using my current formula (w/ updated conditions)? i thought it might be due to the cell formatting, but i changed col R to automatic, plain text, and number format and the `43328` still shows

Comment: 43329, 43328, 43327 etc. are dates formatted as numbers. I would need to see it to tell...

Comment: no, the output of the formula (column R) is a number value (columns Q and B are dates). the formula tells me the time (# days) since opening (col B) and closing (col Q)

Comment: lets see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit#gid=1861601711

Comment: thanks, @user0! the new solution `=IFERROR(IF(P6="never opened", "",
         IF(B6="", "", 
         IF(AND(P6="closed", Q6<"NOW()"), Q6-B6, TODAY()-B6))),)` works wonderfully :)